# sbt multi project does not create standard directories

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

with intellij I create a sbt project. Added to `build.sbt` a subproject like this:

```
lazy val subProject = project in file("subProject")
```

will generate the subproject. I am missing the standard source directories like `src/main/scala src/main/scala2_11` ....

Manual adding will be difficult in the treamtment of IntelliJ. On each sbt update I have to set manual all sources of the subprojects as source folder.

What can I do?

build.sbt:

```
name := "WizardLogisticSystem"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.1"

lazy val scalaV = "2.12.1"

lazy val standardResolver = Seq(
  "Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager" at "http://nexus.intelligyscience.de/content/repositories/thirdparty/",
  "Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager" at "http://nexus.intelligyscience.de/content/repositories/releases/"
)

lazy val standardDeps = Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.17",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-agent" % "2.4.17",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-camel" % "2.4.17",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster" % "2.4.17",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster-metrics" % "2.4.17",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster-sharding" % "2.4.17",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster-tools" % "2.4.17",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-contrib" % "2.4.17",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-multi-node-testkit" % "2.4.17",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-osgi" % "2.4.17",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence" % "2.4.17",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence-tck" % "2.4.17",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-remote" % "2.4.17",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.4.17",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.4.17",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream-testkit" % "2.4.17",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.4.17",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-distributed-data-experimental" % "2.4.17",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-typed-experimental" % "2.4.17",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence-query-experimental" % "2.4.17"
)

lazy val sharedBase = (project in file("sharedBase")).settings(
  scalaVersion := scalaV,
  credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".sbt" / "isCredentials"),
  resolvers ++= standardResolver,
  libraryDependencies ++= standardDeps
)

lazy val dispositionDepartment = (project in file("dispositionDepartment")).settings(
  scalaVersion := scalaV,
  credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".sbt" / "isCredentials"),
  resolvers ++= standardResolver,
  libraryDependencies ++= standardDeps
).enablePlugins(DockerPlugin).dependsOn(sharedBase)
```

my plugins.sbt

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.3")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.1.4")
```

Comment: Do you have some sbt plugins enabled? Some, like `PlayScala` change the directories configuration, and IntelliJ takes them into account.

Comment: Yes the dockerplugin. It should not be a play framework project. Only a distributed akka test :)

Comment: Is the problem that you have to manually mark the directories even if they are already created, or manually create the source folders?

Comment: both manual create and manual mark it

Comment: Source directories aren't automatically created anymore in 2017.1 (except for src/main/scala and src/test/scala), but they should be marked just fine when created. Note that in your project definition you are using scala 2.12, and that a `scala-2.11` directory will not be marked in that case. If no directories are marked at all, please create an issue for us at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL and include the project definition and a screenshot of the modules in the "project structure" dialog

Comment: I created a ticket. #931190  The src/main/scala is created for the root at first startup. After I change the sbt files the target of the subprojects are created but not the the soruces. Even if i created it by self IntelliJ does not recognized it

Comment: I copied now the empty folders of the root in each subproject. Now idea is recognizing the scala directory as sources